# Keycloak locale not set after registration

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

We recently upgraded Keycloak from 3.4.3 to 12.0.2 and since then the users locale is not set anymore during registration.

Previously the locale in the user profile was set to the locale used to display the registration page.

I attached a debugger to a local 12.0.2 keycloak and if you look at the `UserLocaleUpdateAction` the user locale is determined based on the authnote `locale_user_requested`, but this is not set when using the openid-connect registration url (which is created by the keycloak.js `register` function):

`http://localhost/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/registrations?client_id=<clientid>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&state=4917895c-ef91-403c-98ee-49f4025c3018&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=df3574be-ddfc-4d42-8f88-bfc3094e29ff&ui_locales=de&kc_locale=de`

If I go through the login page and click register, I eventually end up on `http://localhost/auth/realms/<realm>/login-actions/registration?client_id=<clientid>....`, from here the locale is set, but I can't seem to access this url directly.

I'm not sure if it is a bug with Keycloak or am I missing some new configuration?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that problem? I am having the same issue right now.

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: Some time has passed, is there any news?

Comment: Relevant issue at keycloak: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/13505